# Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow not working on Classic Outlook Desktop

Tags: webview, outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

The API Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow not working for classic Outlook desktop. The url does not open using webview anymore. However, it works fine for new Outlook Desktop.
Just be be clear I am using the permission ReadWriteItem already in the manifest file.

Below is the code I am using. I am expecting a WebView inside outlook to display the content of the url. This used to work fine up untill now. Suddenly this has stopped working. Though on new Outlook it still works fine.

```
if(Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName!="Outlook")
            {
               window.open( self.accessUrl, "_blank");
            }
            else{
             Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow( self.accessUrl);
            }
```

Comment: What's your classic Outlook desktop version? I just tried it on a recent one and it did work, so I couldn't reproduce.